# How can I dynamically add a pattern image to a svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm new working with SVG images. I'm using them to paint a jacket several times of different colors without needing to have an image for each colour. This is being done with jQuery.

That was the 'easy' part. I solved it by applying `fill: #color;` CSS rule to `<path>` inside `<svg>`.

The hard part is when trying to fill the svg path with an image. It's really weird. My code is printed just fine in the html inside the `<svg>`, but not working at all. And when, in chrome's dev tools, I cut the `<defs>` element, and paste it again exactly where it was, it suddenly works! It's driving me crazy :(.

My code:

```js
var items = [
            {
                title: 'Africa',
                // color: '#776254'
            },
            {
                title: 'Aguamarina',
                // color: '#9cd3be'
            },
            {
                title: 'Aluminio',
                // color: '#9b9b9b'
            },
            {
                title: 'Amarillo Jamaica',
                // color: '#ffcd01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Amatista',
                // color: '#4d4169'
            },
            {
                title: 'Ambar Brillante',
                // color: '#eb6608'
            },
            {
                title: 'Arándano',
                // color: '#604483'
            }
        ];

        $(function () {
            var PrendaShow = {
                $mac_wrapper: $('#prendas-mac-slider-wrapper .mac-slider'),
                $fullprints_wrapper: $('#fullprints-gallery'),
                img: {
                    src: 'image.svg',
                    width: 350,
                    height: 188
                },
                init: function () {
                    this.makeItems();
                    this.bindEvents();
                },
                bindEvents: function () {
                    // events
                },
                makeItems: function() {
                    var self = this,
                        $model = $('<div/>', { class: 'mac-item' });
                    $model.append($('<div/>', { class: 'item-img' }));
                    $.each(items, function() {
                         var $item = $model.clone();
                        self.$mac_wrapper.append($item);
                    });
                    this.svgDraw();
                },
                svgDraw: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    $.get(this.img.src, function(data) {
                        var $svg = self.normalizeSvg(data);
                        self.appendImgs($svg);
                    });
                },
                normalizeSvg: function (data) {
                    var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
                    $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
                    $svg.width(this.img.width).height(this.img.height);
                    return $svg;
                },
                appendImgs: function ($svg) {
                    var items = this.$mac_wrapper.find('.mac-item');
                    $.each(items, function() {
                        var $clone = $svg.clone(),
                            color = $(this).data('color');
                        $clone.find('path').css('fill', 'url(#img1)');
                        var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
                        img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','536');
                        img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','536');
                        img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/daisy-grass-repeating-background.jpg');
                        img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
                        img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
                        img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible')
                        $clone.prepend($('<defs/>').html('<pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100"></pattern>'));
                        $clone.find('pattern').append(img)
                        $(this).find('.item-img').append($clone);
                    });
                }
            };
            PrendaShow.init();
        });
```

```css
#prendas-mac-slider-wrapper {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.mac-slider {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
}
.mac-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  min-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item-img {
  background: url('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Cqi6KXXXXXbpXVXXq6xXFXXXy/Classic-font-b-White-b-font-font-b-Jacket-b-font-font-b-Men-b-font.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}
svg {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="prendas-mac-slider-wrapper" class="row">
                <div class="mac-slider">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**I'm not being able to give my exact example because of images upload**. I really hope you understand what I'm trying to do here, and what's going wrong.

---

**EDIT:** Not sure if this deserves to be in an answer, but I preferred to write it here since I don't think its the right way to do this.

As I knew that, from chrome dev tools, if I deleted the `<defs>` element and pasted it again, it worked, I tried this and worked:

```
var svg_html = $svg.html();
$svg.html('');
$svg.html(svg_html);
```

Comment: Replace $clone.prepend($('<defs/>')... with DOM creation of the defs and pattern elements as you do for the image element.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Nothing changes. Until I 'refresh' the <svg> html, it doesn't take effect

Comment: Can I see the changes you made?

Comment: I would suggest the usage of D3.js; it playes very well with `svg` and all dynamic tasks in 'svg` are breeze in D3.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've changed the complete code now. It's way too large, no way to paste it in here. Anyways, refreshing the html worked ok. Its really weird, but it works.

Comment: @Pankaj I'm trying to use as less external libraries as possible.

Comment: @AlejoAnibal the changes should be the 10 or so lines that DOM create the defs and pattern elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$clone.prepend($('<defs/>').html('<pattern ...
```

You cannot use jQuery to create SVG elements like this.  You are doing it the correct way (with `createElementNS()`) when you create the `<image>` element. But you also need to use the same method when creating the `<defs>` and <`pattern>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it's still not working. As you can see in the EDIT, the error was fixed by 'refreshing' the `<svg>` inner html.